# Simple javascript cause page reload

Tags: javascript

I have a page with some javascript that add or remove some controls. Everything is working perfectly except when the page is viewed from Chrome (PC and ipad version). The problem is that my page reload when a button is clicked. The button event call a function

```
myButton.onclick = function () { myFunction(param1, param2); };
```

and the function is

```
function myFunction(param1, param2)
{ 
    var formToRemove = document.getElementById(param1);
    document.getElementById("div_" + param2).removeChild(formToRemove); 
    return false;
}
```

The 'return false;' is there because one of the post I've read suggested to add that line to prevent the page reload but this haven't helped me so far.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms/10836076#10836076) will help you:

All you need is to assign **type="button"** on your button control.

Your markup would look like the one below:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">My Button Text</button>
```

And I think if you use button with type="button" set on the markup, you probably don't need to return false at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks! I simply added "myButton.type = 'button';" and the reload issue is gone.

Comment: I hate to admit how long I spent trying to debug why my page was reloading.  Who'd have thought that a <button> tag would need a type='button' attribute!!!  I see the difference (and the point, but wow was this subtle (and not at all easy to google an answer for)  Thanks!!!